# Can't get text from editText Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, import

I'm having some issues with my school project. I can't get the text from the textbox. I searched for a solution but nothing found.. I'll be grateful if somebody help me :)

So here is my **Java** code:

```
package com.src.vicnote;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class NewNoteActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button saveButton;
    EditText textData;
    Context context;

    String text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_note);

        saveButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                textData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                text = textData.getText().toString();
                //text = "this is sparta!";
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "string: \"" + text + "\" end of note text");
                new SaveClass(text/*, context.getApplicationContext()*/);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_note, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_note,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

And my **XML**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.src.vicnote.NewNoteActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Save" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also I want to ask you what will happen if the text is cyrillic? Will be there any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't really tell what your error is without a logCat.

but one thing that might fix your problem is replacing

```
textData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
text = textData.getText().toString();
```

with

```
textData = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
text = textData.getText().toString();
// Toast for debugging purposes
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),text,0).show();
```

When using Fragments you should really read about [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView()) & [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()).

### Update

where in the xml have you set the text?

you need to set your text to something before you actually call the getText() command.

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSave"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    ----- add this line ------
    android:text="whatever you want"
    --------------------------
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
```

Good Luck

Comment: I shouldn't have used fragments. All my problems were because there was an editText in my fragment xml and actually I was typing in it, not in the right one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can't really not use fragments. Just think of fragments as re-usable "sub-activities". Did getActivity() work in that case ? Or did you change the name of editText?

Comment: I didn't actually used getActivity, I just removed the textbox from thte fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `getActivity()` did the trick before accessing the editText.

For example:

`EditText addressText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.location);`

Answer (score 0):

getEditableText return an editable object, and you can't edit the object like that, so it is null.

simply use "getText" instead.

I don't know about Cyrillic, but it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to replace getEditableText with getText. I just wanted to try, but when I use getText it fails again..

Comment: If this is useful, all this things are in a second activity created in the main activity.

Comment: generally, an activity should not be created within another activity so you may have a context reference problem. I would suggest not doing that...

Answer (score 0):

Try just this

replace yours:

```
textData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
text = textData.getText().toString();
```

with:

```
textData = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
text = textData.getText().toString();
```

hope it works.